# How to Drag and drop data into specific column in empty table using angular6?

Tags: typescript, angular6

This is my code.

```js
controls:any[] =[];
this.controls.push({'id':101,'name':'one'});
this.controls.push({'id':102,'name':'two'});
this.controls.push({'id':103,'name':'three'});

tables:any[] =[];
 this.tables.push({'id':this.generateUid()+1+'_table','rows':[{'id':this.generateUid()+2+'_row','cols':[{'id':this.generateUid()+3 +'_col','field':{}}]}]});
 generateUid() {
    let d = new Date();
    let uid = d.getTime();
    return uid;
  }
  
  addTable() {
  }
  
  addRow() {
  
  }
  addColumn() {
  }
```

I have controls list those are rendered on left side , when drag one control and drop on to the specific column in table (mutiple rows and columns) using angular6.